# Remove 23:00 from Plotly charts

Tags: python, charts, plotly

I have a plotly chart with dates for the index. All the dates are a day early and show 23:00 at the end of them in the chart. Is it possible to remove this and show the correct date?

Comment: I suspect this is happening because your times are in local time and but are being interpreted as GMT. If you live, for example, in Central European Time, then Monday 00:00 local wall-clock time is Sunday 23:00 GMT. It appears that `plotly` expects your times to be GMT (https://community.plot.ly/t/disable-timezone-change/8992).

Comment: thanks I've done a lot of reading on this and can't figure it out

Comment: weirdly I've merged 2 dataframes together and half the chart is fine and the other half if a day off, however both index's look the same

Comment: I think you may have to convert your data to GMT.